# How to set HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP in Apache http server configuration

Tags: java, apache, web, cloudflare

We have a JSF application , serving the requests via tomcat ajp protocol. The entire web site is sitting behind Cloudflare CDN. When the following code is executed

`String ipaddress = httpServletRequest.getHeader(HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP);`

The ipaddress is always null.

`httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr()`

always gives the cloud flare ip address.

Have found this http://danielmiessler.com/blog/getting-real-ip-addresses-using-cloudflare-nginx-and-varnish for websites using jninix.

Do we have a similar solution for apache  http server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by loading 
LoadModule cloudflare_module modules/mod_cloudflare.so
This sets the remote ip instead of cloudflare's ip